# Haskell Monad task

Tags: haskell, monads

So we have following Data Types:

`data Expr = Num Double | Add Expr Expr | Var Char deriving Show`

and

`type Env = [(Char, Double)]`

Further More we have these two functions:

```
evalDo :: Env -> Expr -> Maybe Double
evalDo _ (Num a) = return a
evalDo e (Var c) = getvar e c
evalDo e (Add a b) = do
    a' <- evalDo e a
    b' <- evalDo e b
    Just (a'+b')
```

and

```
getvar :: Env -> Char -> Maybe Double
getvar [] c = Nothing
getvar ((x,y):es) c 
    | c == x = Just y
    |otherwise = getvar es c
```

So if we would run the following Code:
`evalDo [('x', 2)] (Add (Num 5) (Var 'x'))`, we would receive:`Just 7.0`.
Whereas `evalDo [('x', 2)] (Add (Num 5) (Var 'y'))` evaluates to `Nothing`.

From what I understand when running the former code, our function matches the `evalDo e (Var c) = getvar e c` line. From there it calls `getvar e c` which results in `Just 2`. Then we go back to our original second call, which is
`(Add (Num 5) (Var 'x'))`

. Now the Var 'x' is resolved into `Just 2`. So finally the `evalDo e (Add a b) = do...` function-line matches and we get Just7.0.

Obviously there is a huge major flaw to my explanation, since we try to "Add" Num 5 and Just 2 and by our definition its not possible. Yet the function seems to work flawelessly somehow but I just can't figure it out.

Comment: Not an answer to your question, really, but you might be interested to try puzzling through the equivalent applicative-style implementation too: `evalDo e (Add a b) = liftA2 (+) (evalDo e a) (evalDo e b)`. Or the alternative with punctuation instead of parens: `evalDo e (Add a b) = (+) <$> evalDo e a <*> evalDo e b`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let's break this down into steps. First, `do` notation isn't magic in Haskell. It desugars to ordinary operators. So let's look at your last case in `evalDo`.

```
evalDo e (Add a b) = do
    a' <- evalDo e a
    b' <- evalDo e b
    Just (a'+b')
```

By [the destructuring rules](https://en.m.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/do_notation), this is equivalent to

```
evalDo e (Add a b) =
    evalDo e a >>= \a' ->
    evalDo e b >>= \b' ->
    Just (a' + b')
```

So, when we call `evalDo [('x', 2)] (Add (Num 5) (Var 'x'))`, we *first* match the `Add a b` line. We'll do that case with `a = Num 5` and `b = Var 'x'`. Inside of that branch, we `evalDo` both `a` and `b`.

But we *do not* assign the results to variables. If we had used `let`, then `a'` would be equal to `Just 5` and `b'` to `Just 2`. But that's not what happens. We used `<-`, which desugars to a monadic bind. Let's take the first `evalDo`. It looks like this.

```
evalDo e a >>= \a' -> ...
```

The `evalDo` part returns `Just 5`. The `>>=` operator (usually pronounced "bind") on `Maybe` is [defined as](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.16.2.0/docs/src/GHC.Base.html#line-1048)

```
(Just x) >>= k      = k x
Nothing  >>= _      = Nothing
```

If the left-hand evaluates to a `Just`, then the right-hand (which is a function) is called with the *inside* of that `Just` as an argument. If the left-hand evaluates to `Nothing`, then the right-hand (which is, again, a function) is *never called*.

In our case, `evalDo e a` evaluated to `Just 5`, so we call the lambda function with argument `5`. The lambda calls its argument `a'`, so we have `a'` equal to `5`, the inside of the `Just`.

The same thing happens in the second case, with `Just 2` instead of `Just 5`. If we had given it a variable name that didn't exist, then we would get a `Nothing`, the lambda would never be called, and the entire function would return `Nothing`. The `do` notation just makes all of this higher-order function nonsense transparent, so we don't have to think about it as much.

```
evalDo e (Add a b) = do
    a' <- evalDo e a
    b' <- evalDo e b
    Just (a'+b')
```

Going back to this, the way you should read this normally is "evaluate `a`, evaluate `b`, and return `a' + b'`". The `<-` bindings carry some context with them. In your case, that context is failure via `Maybe`, but in principle it could be [a local variable](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers-0.6.0.4/docs/Control-Monad-Trans-State-Lazy.html#t:StateT), [nondeterminism](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/monads-tf-0.1.0.3/docs/Control-Monad-List.html#v:ListT), or even [a continuation](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers-0.6.0.4/docs/Control-Monad-Trans-Cont.html#t:ContT). The way this is *implemented* is via lambdas, but in the usual course of programming in Haskell and writing `do` notation, you don't think about it as such.

Answer (score 4):

I think the part you are missing is that `<-` is not simply an assignment operator; it "opens" the `Just` value and binds what it finds to `a'` and `b'`. Desugaring the `do` block gives

```
evalDo e (Add a b) = 
    evalDo e a >>= \a' -> 
    evalDo e b >>= \b' -> 
    Just (a' + b')
```

Let's look at `>>=` for `Maybe` types.

```
Nothing >>= _ = Nothing
Just x >>= f = f x -- Call f on x, not on Just x
```

If `evalDo e a` produces `Nothing`, we can ignore the rest of the `do` block and evaluate directly to `Nothing`. But if it's a `Just 5`, we bind 5 (not `Just 5`) to `a'` and continue. The same thing happens with `evalDo e b`: either we get `Just 2`, bind 2 to `b'`, and continue, or immediately return `Nothing`.

Only if *both* recursive calls produce `Just` values do we reach the final line where we can now add `5 + 2` and wrap the result in `Just`.